# Issues with inserting a many to many relationship in Remix/Prisma

Tags: prisma, remix.run

I am checking out and learning the Remix framework along with the Prisma ORM that comes with it.
I am trying to create a simple blog in order to learn the framework but have come up with an issue when inserting into a many to many relationship.

This is my schema:

```
model Post {
  id           Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  slug         String @unique
  title        String
  markdown     String
  postImageUrl String
  ogLocale     String @default("en_US")
  tags         TagsOnPosts[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId String
}

model Tag {
  id   Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  posts TagsOnPosts[]
}

model TagsOnPosts {
  post       Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId     Int
  tag        Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
  tagId      Int
  assignedAt DateTime @default(now())
  assignedBy String

  @@id([postId, tagId])
}
```

and this is the function I call in order to create a new blog post:

```
export async function createPost(
  post: Pick<Post, "slug" | "title" | "markdown" | "postImageUrl">,
  tags: string[]
) {
  const tagsCreate = tags.map((tag) => {
    return {
      name: tag,
      tag: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: { name: tag },
          create: { name: tag },
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      slug: post.slug,
      title: post.title,
      markdown: post.markdown,
      postImageUrl: post.postImageUrl,
      tags: {
        create: tagsCreate
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I'm getting some typing issues from typescript which is hard to grok:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: string; tag: { connectOrCreate: { where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; }; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type '(Without<TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput, TagsOnPostsUncheckedCreateWithoutPostInput> & TagsOnPostsUncheckedCreateWithoutPostInput) | ... 5 more ... | undefined'.   Type '{ name: string; tag: { connectOrCreate: { where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; }; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Without<TagsOnPostsUncheckedCreateWithoutPostInput[], TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput[]> & TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput[]'.     Type '{ name: string; tag: { connectOrCreate: { where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; }; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput[]'.       Property 'assignedBy' is missing in type '{ name: string; tag: { connectOrCreate: { where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; }; }; }; }' but required in type 'TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput'.  index.d.ts(8595, 5): 'assignedBy' is declared here.
```

I guess there is a problem with the way I'm trying to build the query up and I am guessing there is an easier way but I can't figure it out.

**I just want to send in an array of tags and create new ones of the ones that don't exist and connect the other ones that do to the post.**

Thanks for your sage advice and better wisdom!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question but it was a bit different than the solved solution:

```
export async function createPost(
  post: Pick<Post, "slug" | "title" | "markdown" | "postImageUrl">,
  tags: string[],
  userId: string
) {
  const tagsCreate = tags.map((tag) => {
    return {
      tag: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: { name: tag },
          create: { name: tag },
        }
      },
      assignedBy: userId
    }
  }).filter(Boolean);

  return prisma.post.create({
    include: {
      tags: true,
    },
    data: {
      slug: post.slug,
      title: post.title,
      markdown: post.markdown,
      postImageUrl: post.postImageUrl,
      userId: userId, // provide the userId here
      tags: {
        create: tagsCreate
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting indicates that the `assignedBy` field is missing in your `tagsCreate` data object.

This is required because in your `TagsOnPosts` model, you have specified the `assignedBy` field which is not nullable and you haven't provided a default value.

Also, you're trying to connect or create tags directly in the `tagsCreate` object, but you should create or connect tags in the `TagsOnPosts` model, because it is the junction table that connects posts and tags.

You can modify the `createPost` function to fix these issues:

```js
export async function createPost(
  post: Pick<Post, "slug" | "title" | "markdown" | "postImageUrl">,
  tags: string[],
  userId: string
) {
  const tagsCreate = tags.map((tag) => {
    return {
      tag: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: { name: tag },
          create: { name: tag },
        }
      },
      assignedBy: userId
    }
  });

  return prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      slug: post.slug,
      title: post.title,
      markdown: post.markdown,
      postImageUrl: post.postImageUrl,
      userId: userId, // provide the userId here
      tags: {
        create: tagsCreate
      }
    }
  });
}
```

In this version of the function, I assume that you're providing the `userId` as an argument to the function. If the `userId` is not available in this way, you will need to fetch or determine it in some other way before creating the post.

Comment: Thanks, still got some typing issues however:
```
TS2322: Type '{ name: string; tag: { connectOrCreate: { where: { name: string; }; create: { name: string; }; }; }; assignedBy: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '(Without<TagsOnPostsCreateWithoutPostInput, TagsOnPostsUncheckedCreateWithoutPostInput> & TagsOnPostsUncheckedCreateWithoutPostInput) | ... 5 more ... | undefined'. [...]```

Comment: Having a little bit of a hard time understanding the output typescript yells at me since I'm very new to Prisma